# Create SVGPoint inside an element with user coordinate

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a small project (to learn SVG) running (using javascript).

I would like to be able to track a point in a shape with its own user coordinate system. My idea is to find the coordinates of the point within the shape, then create an SVGPoint, so that I can pass on that element. I have seen the method create SVGPoint in examples, but it seems it is used in the context of the 'SVG_root' (that is, document.documentElement.createSVGPoint() works).

When I use (in Firefox)

```
inSvgObj.createSVGPoint()
```

where inSVGObj is a  element, the web console says "TypeError: inSvgObj.createSVGPoint is not a function". Is it possible to create an SVG point within the  to subsequently set with values representing coordinates in that 's user coordinate system?

EDIT (after considernig Robert Longson's answer):
Given that SVGPoint is created only within an "SVG root" and that I have been unable to find a way to move that to within another element, I have found more convenient to use a different svg element type: SVGMatrix. In case it helps someone (as I have spent some time trying to deal with this),It is possible to manipulate analogue values inside an SVG Point by creating an SVGMatrix that would work as a simulated point (for the purposes of coordinates. To that endthe methods `.createSVGMatrix()`, `getCTM()` and`.multiply()` (this last from SVGMatrix) are used. To illustrate that, I will include a (js) function that takes 4 arguments: x-coordinate in user coordinate system (ucs) to transform, y-coordinate is that ucs, object whose ucs is the want we want to transform and an object in the ucs we want to transform to; and returns am object with thrre poperties the x-coordinate in the transformed ucs, its y-coordinate and 1 (for consistency with SVG Recommendations).

```
function coorUcsAToUcsB(ucsAx,ucsAy,svgObjUcsA,svgObjUcsB){
  var ctmUcsA=svgObjUcsA.getCTM();
  var ctmUcsB=svgObjUcsB.getCTM().inverse();
  var mtx=document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].createSVGMatrix();
  mtx.e=ucsAx;
  mtx.f=ucsAy;
  var simulSvgP=ctmUcsB.multiply(ctmUcsA.multiply(mtx)); //1
  return {"x":simulSvgP.e,"y":simulSvgP.f,"z":1};
}
```

//1 this line creates an svg matrix with 1st and 2nd column at 0, 3rd with coordinates of ucsB from the analogue svg matrix with coordinates in ucsA - it takes the coordinates in ucsA to viewport's cs and from there to coordinates in ucsB. For the matrix operation explanation, see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20000802/coords.html#NestedTransformations).

Any comments, in particular having overlooked a existing method that does the same or any drawbacks, will be more than welcome.

Comment: SVGPoints are in [SVGPointList](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGPointList) [polylines and polygons](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#PolylineElement) have an SVGAnimatedPoints interface which has SVGPointList members. If you need more information, ask another question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will take a new look. I came across SVGPointsList but could not see a way to use the interface easily. But, it seems it's worth a closer look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the SVG Point using the root element creation but once you've done that you can set whatever values in it you want. When you assign those values to an object the object will interpret them in its coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer which implies that SVG Points need to be created inside an svg-tag element. I have been thinking in several porssibilities, but how would I go changing the values (from 0,0 in svg root coordinate system) to values in the user (eg, inSVGObj mentioned above which is a <g>) coordinate system. The SVGPoint is "appended" to svg root, can I use a method t move that over to within an arbitary object, could you suggest a method (I have tried `code` inSvgObj.appendChild(svgPoint_root) but Typeerror has said "Value does not implement interface Node.").